# How can we add existing file to VS code solution, I am not getting 'Add existing item' option

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can we add existing file or folder to VS code solution from explorer itself ?
One way is to add from file explorer but can this be done from VS code explorer itself like other Visual studio IDE solution explorer ?

Comment: VSC is not an IDE, it has no knowledge of the build system used so it can't edit that file for you, maybe you can find an extension that supports your build system

Comment: Thanks @rioV8 and NanoBit for your responses. I could find one extension for Solution explorer by publisher:"Fernando Escolar". Although I am still facing issues with opening existing repo folder with this, seems to be more suitable for new solutions and adding existing project to the same.

 Let me know if you are using any.

Answer (score 1):

We can't add it like Visual Studio IDE as how you will always have a link to it.

However, you can "Open" a file temporarily via Cntrl+O or can open a new Window with that other folder opened.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the existing file can be inserted by copying to system's clipboard then paste from VSC.

To copy to system's clipboard:

`xclip <filename>`

Then paste to VSC as usual using Ctrl-V.